# Proper formatting for Array within JSON from iOS using NSURLSessionDataTask

Tags: objective-c, json, nsarray, nsjsonserialization

I'm trying to do a POST to a RESTful Web API and having issues with the format on the httpBody. `NSJSONSerialization` is creating this:

```
{
  "UserId" : "ThisIsMe",
  "Locations" : "[\n  \"1\"\n]",
  "TypeOfValue" : "3",
  "SomeTypeID" : 22,
  "Title" : "asdfadsf",
  "Description" : "Description"
}
```

But what I need is this:

```
{
  "UserId" : "ThisIsMe",
  "Locations" : ["1"],
  "TypeOfValue" : "3",
  "SomeTypeID" : 22,
  "Title" : "asdfadsf",
  "Description" : "Description"
}
```

In order to put this together "as is" I had to take an `NSArray` run `NSJSONSerialization` on it then append that to an `NSDictionary` and then call `NSJSONSerialization` on that. So there is a problem obviously with the double serialization, but if I pass in the array with the `NSDictionary` it fails...help please.

Comment: How does it fail if the dictionary contains the array? What is the returned error / JSON?

Comment: It's not a valid format. The expectation is that you get an array, not a string which is what "["1","4"]" is because the array tags are wrapped as strings within double quotes. Also it's creating carriage returns but that has more to do with the options being set for prettyprinting.

Comment: That is a description of what is wrong with your current code, not the previous solution you had and say didn't work (but which I think it the correct approach)

Comment: Correct, the question is how do you get it to serialize it into the second structure. I hand did that for purposes of demonstration as that's what works. I'm using RestClient in firefox as a means to determine what does and does not work. The problem remains how to get Objective-C to put it into the correct format.

Comment: You have placed a string rather than array in the dictionary as the "Locations" value.  Don't do that.  Show us the code that creates the dictionary and adds "Locations".

Comment: "I had to take an NSArray run NSJSONSerialization on it then append that to an NSDictionary" -- No you didn't -- you had to go out of your way to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have an `NSDictionary` whose keys are all strings and whose values are `NSString`, `NSNumber` or `NSArray` (containing `NSString`) instances. Then, use `NSJSONSerialisation` to convert that dictionary representation into a JSON data representation and you will get what you want.